# Ruby case statement not returning when condition evaluates to true

Tags: ruby

Ruby newbie here. I've written a case statement to check whether a string parameter ends with "?", and I don't understand the result. Here's my code:

```
class Bob
  def self.hey(phrase)
    case phrase
    when phrase.chars.last == "?"
      'Sure.'
    else
      'Whatever.'
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `Bob.hey("Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?")` I get back *Whatever.*, despite `"Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?".chars.last == "?"` evaluating to *true* in IRB. I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove `phrase` from the first part of the case statement or change it to `phrase[-1]` and make the first condition `when '?'`. Right now, with your given example, it roughly evaluates to `when  "Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?" == (phrase.chars.last == "?")` which in turn becomes `"Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?" == true` (which is `false` thus else)

Comment: Ah, yeah. That makes sense. Is there a way to use a case statement or something similar with conditions that evaluate different conversions of the argument, i.e. `when phrase.chars.last == "?"` and also `when phrase.scan(/\w+/).empty?`? Or would I have to write that as an if/elsif?

Comment: you can certainly do that just don't place an evaluation after case. e.g. `case; when when phrase.chars.last == "?"` is very different from `case phrase; when phrase.chars.last == "?"`

Comment: As this is a case statement, you are testing `(phrase.chars.last == "?") === phrase`, syntactic sugar for (`phrase.chars.last == "?").===phrase`. The doc [String#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) tells us that `===` is equivalent to [String#==](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) when the right side of the equality is a string. Therefore, you are testing `*phrase.chars.last == "?") == phrase`. As the left sied is `true` or `false` and the right side is a string this will always be false. Note `===` is defined differently in other classes.

Answer (score 2):

There's two forms of the `case` statement, one where you specify `case expr` and another where you don't. In the first form the `expr` value is tested against all of the branches with `===`. In the second form each branch is evaluated like an `if` would be.

This means there's two ways to fix this. Either drop the term from the `case` part:

```
def self.hey(phrase)
  case
  when phrase.chars.last == "?"
    'Sure.'
  else
    'Whatever.'
  end
end
```

Or switch the `case` to focus on the important part:

```
def self.hey(phrase)
  case phrase.chars.last
  when "?"
    'Sure.'
  else
    'Whatever.'
  end
end
```

Another way to do this is to use a regular expression:

```
def self.hey(phrase)
  case phrase
  when /\?\z/
    'Sure.'
  else
    'Whatever.'
  end
end
```

Where `/\?\z/` means "question mark character at end of string.

Comment: Ah, that's the bit I was missing. I didn't realize I could write case without defining the expression. Thank you!

Comment: Ruby does have an unusually flexible `case` statement which is the source of much confusion. You're not alone here!

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two cases, an `if/else` is more than enough:

```
if phrase.chars.last == "?"
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Note that you could use [`end_with?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) :

```
if phrase.end_with?('?')
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks. There will actually be 4 cases in total, but they evaluate different parts of the phrase, i.e. `when phrase.chars.last == "?"`, `when phrase == phrase.upcase` , `when phrase.scan(/\w+/).empty?` and an `else`. But it sounds like this will have to be written as an if/elsif anyway.